# How to use Google Maps for more than just an overlay

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, google-maps, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 SP1 and I have defined the annual risk of accidents for each segment of a city road network.

I would like to know if anyone tried to do more than overlay on Google Maps or similar...

For instance, is there a way of using their services to return a path from A to B, based on my data? We could call it, "return the safest path from A to B", instead of the traditional shortest/fastest one?

I don't know if it's relevant or not, but my network doesn't completely match OSM data in ArcGIS (it was created that way and with a different datum ... so, it may be also due to the geographic transformation applied).

If there is a way, can it be achieved with my current license?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to use Google's API at all for this. You have all the data locally, so use a local software solution. Given that, I would suggest editing the question to focus on that aspect rather than the Google Maps aspect.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is finding the best route along a network which has each segment assigned an impedance representing risk of accident.

For this you could use a license for the **Network Analyst** extension to ArcGIS for Desktop.

A good place to start reading about this topic is **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000032000000)**.

Having the route based on your assigned impedances solved using Google Maps may be possible but I think you would be looking at considerably more in development and licensing costs.

Comment: Thank you, @PolyGeo!It is exactly what I thought/read. I have an ArcGIS student license and I don't know if I can get Network Analyst. Even so, is there another viable alternative to Google Maps for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There is tool for "shortest path" in QGIS which is free. I guess you could configure it for using it with your params.

If you feel confident with a bit of sql and programming, you could also use the combo postgis/pgrouting which works perfectly for this kind of problem as well.